# Saving image to camera roll in iOS Safari always converts it to jpg

Tags: ios, canvas, mobile-safari

In my web app (runs in native Safari not `UIWebView`) I am using canvas to basically allow to draw an image. The user should then be able to save this image to his computer, however it's very important that this process is lossless. That's why I am using the PNG file format.

All this works perfectly on desktop, and in theory it should also work on iOS because by tap and holding the resulting image can be saved to the camera roll. The problem occurs if the image is later imported into the app again. On inspection of the uploaded image type you can see that the image is now in the JPG file format and no longer a pixel perfect representation of the drawing the user made.

Is that a general issue with the camera roll on iOS? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

YES, The default file format is JPG while saving image to camera roll. You can save a image in PNG format in a native app by writing some code. But in Safari, there may no be possible to save as PNG format.